# Transformation and its adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

For $V$ a vector space.

Let $T\colon V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation of a finite dimensional inner product space.

How can I prove that $\ker(T^* T + TT^*) = $\ker(T)$\cap$$\ker(T^*)$?

And what is the meaning of $\ker(T^*T + TT^*)$ ?

Is  $\ker(T^*T + TT^*)=\ker(T^*T)+\ker(TT^*)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$\ker(T^*T+TT^*)$ is the set of all $x\in V$ such that $$(T^*T+TT^*)x=0, $$
that is 
$$ T^*Tx+TT^*x=0.$$
This is not the same as the set of all vectors $x$ that can writtten as $x=y+z$ with $T^*Ty=0$ and $TT^*z=0$. I.e., in general $\ker(T^*T+TT^*)\ne\ker(T^*T)+\ker(TT^*)$.

Comment: thank you for the editing and the answer, do you got a hint for the question ?

Answer (score -1):

any suggestion ?

I know how to prove that for every vector that is in the kernel of T and T*

is also at the kernel of TT*+T*T (very trivial).

but how to prove the other side ?